# Bypass windows protection to allow autohotkey send

Tags: autohotkey

For Example if I do this:

```
run Notepad.exe
sleep 500
send, test
return
```

It will run when I'm logged in remotely, but if I schedule a task to run this .ahk it will run it but will stop a the send command.

I know of a solution to not logout normally but to run another .bat command:

```
C:\Windows\System32\tscon.exe 0 /dest:console
C:\Windows\System32\tscon.exe 1 /dest:console
C:\Windows\System32\tscon.exe 2 /dest:console
C:\Windows\System32\tscon.exe 2 /dest:console
C:\Windows\System32\tscon.exe 3 /dest:console
C:\Windows\System32\tscon.exe 4 /dest:console
C:\Windows\System32\tscon.exe 5 /dest:console
```

but my computer is set to restart ever 3 days and then it will not work anymore.

Edit: It does start Notepad, because Notepad is visible when I login but it just cannot trigger the keystrokes.

***TASK SCHEDULER SETTINGS***

**[GENERAL]**

Checked - Run whether user is logged on or not
Checked - Run with highest privileges

**[SETTINGS]**

Checked - Allow task to be run on demand
if the task is already running, then the following rule applies:
Do not Start a new instance

Please Help. Thanks.

Comment: If there's no Notepad UI running/visible with the task executes (ie: the task runs while not logged in), then I'd suspect the problem may be that there's no place for AHK to "send" the keystrokes to.

Comment: It does start Notepad, because Notepad is visible so it just cannot trigger keystrokes.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include the Task configurations you've tried?

Comment: Are you running the task as your user?  Have you tried it with "Run with highest privileges" unchecked?  How about if you tell it to run only while you're logged in?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I tried all possible combinations. also, when I'm logged on it works without any problems. I don't think it's a task schedule problem but more of a windows security measure to block programs like key-loggers, I have alot tried to disable my anti-virus software and UAC but that did not work.

Comment: If it's only failing when you're not logged in, then I'm back to what I suggested originally -- you're not logged in, so there's no desktop, therefor no UI for the `send` to send keystrokes to.  I'm also confused as to why you'd say "Notepad is visible" when you're not logged in?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't see the window on the screen, you can't send to it, as the comments have pointed out.

Try using `ControlSend` which does not require the window to be active.  I haven't tested the code below... maybe something you can play with.  The `WinExist()` statement gets the ID of the newly created notepad window... if you have more than one window open then you will need to delineate which one and take more care in deriving this perhaps, but it's good for a test case where notepad isn't running at all and then you start a window.  You could also replace the sleep statement with `WinWait` in that case.

```
run Notepad.exe
sleep 1000
ControlSend,, test, % "ahk_id" WinExist("ahk_exe notepad.exe")
return
```